# Interfacing Figaro TGS2600

Tags: sensors

I am trying to interface TGS 2600 gas sensor to Arduino, particularly to detect methane gas.
Can anyone tell me the conversion equation between Rs/Ro and ppm, so that I can get ppm values from the Rs/Ro ratio. I am looking to detect between 1-10ppm.